# Created a title for my NavigationBar programmatically, however, not appear in the correct location?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[image]Hi,

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out with my below question.

I created a `UINavigationBar` class, which I created an instance from in the `ViewController` that I would like to implement it in. However, the title for the NavigationBar is not appearing where I want it to. As illustrated the title is currently getting displayed at the very top of the NavigationBar (i.e., in the dark blue area). How can I make the title appears in the light blue color area? And how can I modify its position within the NavigationBar area as desired?

Thanks,
Shadi.

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupNavigationBar()  
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupNavigationBar()
    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        isTranslucent = true
        backgroundColor = .blue
        barStyle = .blackTranslucent
        var fsafdsaf = topItem?.title
        fsafdsaf = "dsadfsadfsafsdafsad"
        let titlfsdfe = UINavigationItem.init(title: fsafdsaf!)
        setItems([titlfsdfe], animated: false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to sort out my issue, however, any further alternatives are much welcomed.

Basically, I added a UILabel to my Navigation Bar in my UINavigationBar Class and managed to sort out the issue.

Refer to below code for solution:[image]

```
import UIKit

import ChameleonFramework

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupNavigationBar()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupNavigationBar()

    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {

        isTranslucent = true

        backgroundColor = .blue

        barStyle = .blackTranslucent

        let navigationBarTitleFrame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 50, width: 120, height: 25)

        let navigationBarTitle = UILabel(frame: navigationBarTitleFrame)

        navigationBarTitle.text = "This is my title"

        navigationBarTitle.textAlignment = .center

        navigationBarTitle.textColor = .white

        navigationBarTitle.layer.borderWidth = 3.0

        self.addSubview(navigationBarTitle)

    }

}
```